# Line integral comparison, multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, line-integrals

I have a question on line integrals. If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the circular disks inscribing and circumscribing $R$, （$R= [−r,r]×[−r,r]$） does it mean the line integral of $e^{−(x^2+y^2)}$ over $C_1$ is smaller than $R$ smaller than $C_2$ because the area of $C_1$ is smaller than $R$ smaller than $C_2$? Can I compare line integrals using their area bounded by the curve if they are in $2D$?

Comment: 1. What is $R$? What is "the same function"? 2. The second clause of the second sentence contains no verb. The third sentence contains pronouns whose meaning is unclear because "line integrals" and "area" are apparently being compared; could you please clarify? In the meantime, voting to close.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I just edited it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean line integrals (over the boundary), or two-dimensional integrals (over the enclosed regions)? The line integrals over circles centered at the origin eventually decrease as the radius increases, while the two-dimensional integrals increase with radius.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes I mean the double integrals over the enclosed regions. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. To do a double integral , you have to find an equivalent vector field that results in same integral and then you can apply Green's theorem to convert it into a double integral. But in this case, directly doing line integral is more straightforward and you can confirm by line integral that it is indeed decreasing as radius inreases.

Comment: For clarity, since the question is not about line integrals, it's advisable to delete the word "line" in the title and body of the question. <> The answer to your question is "yes" because $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ is positive. Generally, integrating over a larger region does not give a larger value of an integral.